# 401 error calling Web API Core from WCF service

Tags: wcf, asp.net-core-webapi, http-status-code-401

I am trying to call a .net core web api from WCF service.

here is my code:

```
  var client = new HttpClient();

    
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://...");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
   
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/tasks");
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

the response returns with 401 error: Unauthorized.

my web api supports both windows and anonymous authentication and I add "*" to allowed cors origins :

```
   services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
        {
            builder
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials()
       
           .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200","http://...", "*");
        }));
```

the get function in my web api controller is:

```
  // GET api/tasks
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
```

still the same error response. any idea why?

Comment: It has nothing to do with Cors.  Do your API need a JWT?

Comment: @serge- no, it does not, as I wrote before it supports nonymous authentication

Comment: Can you post an ApI are you calling with controller together, pls?

Comment: Thanks, but I can see GetAsync("api/tasks"); Where is your api/tasks action?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have  a bug in your url.

Try this:

```
 HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/tasks/get");
```

Comment: Did you check developer tools? There are usually more explanations.

Comment: And try to add  an attribute route to your action    [HttpGet("~/api/tasks/get") ]   public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()

Answer (score 0):

So, for me it was apparently an authentication problem.

I removed windows authentication from my web api and allowed only anonymous authentication.

it worked for me.